How to populate an ACF gallery field from two Woo fields?
I am trying to get the images from two separate places to a single field in ACF.
I have found two working codes for getting the Woo Product Image to an ACF field and the Woo Product Gallery to another ACF field.
Basically I need help with the code to make it combine the two.
I want to get them to populate the same ACF field, so that the whole Product Imagery is combined to be used for a slider. (I couldn't find any information on how WooCommerce does this natively on the product page...) This is the source website: https://cfxdesign.com/how-to-use-acf-fields-for-woocommerce-product-photos/
This is the code I found for getting the Product Image:
function load_existing_product_photo_into_acf_image_field($field) {
global $post;
$field\['value'\] = get_post_meta($post-\>ID, '\_thumbnail_id', true);
return $field;
}
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=product_photo', 'load_existing_product_photo_into_acf_image_field');

And here is the second one for getting the Product Gallery:
function load_existing_product_gallery_into_acf_gallery_field($field) {
    global $post;
    $field['value'] = explode(',', get_post_meta($post->ID, '_product_image_gallery', true));
    return $field;
  }
  add_filter('acf/load_field/name=product_gallery', 'load_existing_product_gallery_into_acf_gallery_field');

I have tried all I could with my non-existent knowledge of PHP but I just can't find information how to combine the two results into one.
It's a really dumb problem but here I am, I spent way too many hours looking for a solution myself.
Thanks in advance

Since you want to merge you dont need to combine in backend as you will need always check if there is new image and update the field etc. So for frontend grab all image ids set in product gallery $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids(); and for the ACF field make sure you get the ids too (that depends how you setup your field). Then merge both arrays in one - https://stackoverflow.com/a/10572576/13378498 . Here is example mergin custom field into gallery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62434585/moving-custom-field-images-to-product-gallery-woocommerce
